# "Incorrect syntax near '{'" calling SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

I am trying to get results from my stored procedure and I am getting `ERROR: Incorrect syntax near '{'.` . I saw many examples using the same thing for a `sql string` and I am not sure why I am getting an error..I have the same amount of parameters...

when I execute my stored procedure om my database like this

`exec rptGetAssetbyLocation '2122`' I get my 5 columns

how do I get results back using Callable Statement ? I am doing something wrong with a `registerOutParameter` ?

```
try
        {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                                String url = "jdbc:sqlserver:...";
                                String username = "username";
                                String password = "password";

                    sb.append("<table id=\"examplee\" border=1 >" 
                    + "<tr><td>ID</td><td>TAG</td><td>NAME</td>"
                        + "<td>MODEL</td><td>SERIAL NUMBER</td></tr>");

            String query = "{exec rptGetAssetbyLocation(?,?,?,?,?)}";
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                    CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);


                                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();


            while (rs.next())
            {
                int id = rs.getInt("ID");
                String tag = rs.getString("tag");
                String name = rs.getString("name"); 
                String model = rs.getString("model"); 
                String serNum = rs.getString("serialNumber");

                sb.append("<tr><td>" + id + "</td>" 
                        + "<td>" + tag + "</td>" 
                        + "<td>" + name + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + model + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + serNum + "</td></tr>");
            }
            sb.append("</table>");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            sb.append("<h1>ERROR: " + e.getMessage() + "</h1>");
        }
        sb.append("</body></html>");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(sb);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you do to run your Stored Procedure in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is

```sql
exec rptGetAssetbyLocation '2122'
```

then you probably don't need to mess with output parameters, you can just use the one input parameter to call your Stored Procedure and then retrieve the results from the ResultSet like this

```java
String query = "exec rptGetAssetbyLocation ?";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
stmt.setString(1, "2122");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next())
{
    int id = rs.getInt("ID");
    String tag = rs.getString("tag");
    String name = rs.getString("name"); 
    String model = rs.getString("model"); 
    String serNum = rs.getString("serialNumber");
    // ...and do other useful stuff
}
```

Comment: OMG!...where you at so I can give you the biggest hug man...I have been trying to solve this for the last two days and had no luck!..thank you so much....

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [the answer by Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23048021/466862), you could also use the JDBC call escape for stored procedures.

JDBC escapes are very specific escapes defined in the JDBC standard to bridge differences between SQL implementations. The JDBC escapes are translated to the database server specific syntax.

For calling stored procedures the escape is:

```
{call procname(arg1, ..,)}
```

or for a stored procedure with a return value:

```
{? = procname(arg1, ...)}
```

Where `arg1` etc is either a literal value or a parameter placeholder. See the [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) apidoc. When prepared or executed, the driver will translate this to the database syntax (ie `EXEC procname arg1, ...` in the case of SQL server).

The syntax you tried to use in your question is a mix between a JDBC escape (the `{...}`) and the SQL Server specific syntax of executing a stored procedure.

Also the result of your stored procedure is probably not an out parameter, but a `ResultSet`, but this depends on the stored procedure definition.

Comment: thanks for a great explanation, oh Ive never been so frustrated I've been making so many mistakes...do you prefer mysql/oracle over sql server when you are working with JDBC ? or it doesn't matter...

Comment: I prefer firebird, but that is because I develop its JDBC driver. However given the JDBC standard, use of databases is largely interchangeable, although each driver and dbms has their own interpretation and quirks.